# SQL query: how to get users and their three latest posts?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a simple schema of two tables, `users` and `posts`. The `posts` table has a foreign key to `users` indicating who authored the post.

Also, let's say I want to list the users and their 3 most-recent posts. I can do this in O(n) queries (1 to list users, 1 for each user getting their posts), but how would I do this in O(1) queries?

Either one query to get the users and posts all at once, or 2 queries, one to get the users and one to get the posts. Assume I would de-dupe any repeated user data.

Comment: Which DBMS? If it supports Windoew Aggregate Functions, i.e. ROW_NUMBER, it's easy, otherwise ...

Comment: I'm curious about any way to do it, so if you'd like to assume postgres (which has window functions) then that's OK. If it can be done without (let's say SQLite), even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self join that should work on most db's. This assumes that `post_time` is unique per user. If that's not the case, then you can replace `on p2.post_time >= p.post_time` with `on p2.id >= p.id`.

```
select u.username, p.id, p.title
from user u join
(
    select p.id, p.title, p.user_id 
    from posts p join posts p2
    on p2.user_id = p.user_id
    and p2.post_time >= p.post_time
    group by p.id, p.title, p.user_id
    having count(*) <= 3
) p on u.id = p.user_id
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL (supported by a wide range of DBMS):

```
select *
from (
   select u.username,
          p.title, 
          row_number() over (partition by u.id order by p.post_time desc) as rn
   from users u
     join posts p on u.id = p.user_id
) t
where rn <= 3
order by u.username;
```

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, window functions are OK but if it can be done without I'd be even more interested.

Comment: @coleifer . . . Window functions are often the fastest and best way to do things, when they can be used.  Why would you not want to use them?

Comment: Gordon -- SQLite does not support them, and I frequently use SQLite. Finding a lowest-common-denominator solution is of interest to me. Plus I'm just burning with curiosity how it might be done without window functions :)

Comment: @coleifer: "*lowest common denominator*" is another way of saying: "it runs equally slow on all platforms"

Comment: If you don't know how to do it without window functions that's fine, but you don't have to be snide. I'm just curious how it would be done on SQLite since I use it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in any database:

```
select u.username, p.title, p.post_time
  from users u
  join posts p
    on u.id = p.user_id
 where p.post_time >=
       (select max(z.post_time)
          from posts z
         where z.user_id = p.user_id
           and z.post_time <
               (select max(y.post_time)
                  from posts y
                 where y.user_id = p.user_id
                   and y.post_time <
                       (select max(x.post_time)
                          from posts x
                         where x.user_id = p.user_id)))
```

Comment: @coleifer it calculates the third highest post_time value for the user_id on the given row, and filters in on rows where the post_time is greater than or equal to that calculated post_time (therein filtering in on the user's last three posts)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Users a
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM posts z
WHERE a.User_ID = z.User_ID
ORDER BY z.post_time DESC
) b
```

Comment: Or outer apply if you want to inc users with no posts